# Format data using Awk Statemnt

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have data like

```
name1 123
name1 324
name2 123
name2 324
name2 456
```

Now I want O/P like

```
name1 123
      324
name2 123
      324
      456
```

Name should not repeat again

Comment: any attempts? ..

Comment: Trying to compare  previous line and current line by the field, but not able to get in awk

Answer (score 2):

**Source**

```
name1 123
name1 324
name2 123
name2 324
name2 456
```

**Code**

```
awk '{$1= a[$1]++ ? "" : $1}1' OFS="\t" file
```

**Results**

```
name1    123
         324
name2    123
         324
         456
```

**Explanation**

Let's use the [*ternary*](https://klashxx.github.io/ternary-operator) operator.

If the our key `$1`, the first field is seen in the array `a[$1]++` then set the first field to null string `""`, if not then the actual value is preserved.

The `1` at the end is just a *shortcut* to avoid using the print statement.

In awk when a condition gets matched the default action is to print the input line.

```
$ echo "test" |awk '1'
```

Is equivalent to:

```
echo "test"|awk '1==1'

echo "test"|awk '{if (1==1){print}}'
```

That's because `1` will be always true

*Last step*  set de `O`utput `F`ield `S`eparator to `TAB` `OFS="\t"` to get our expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is sorted then try this [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$ cat file
name1 123
name1 324
name2 123
name2 324
name2 456
```

**For sorted file**

```
$ awk '$1!=p{print;p=$1;next}{printf("%*s %s\n",length(p)," ",$2)}' file
name1 123
      324
name2 123
      324
      456
```

**For unsorted file**

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$1 in a ? sprintf("%s\n%*s %s",a[$1],length($1)," ",$2): $2}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' file
name1 123
      324
name2 123
      324
      456
```

**Better Readable version**

```
awk '
     {
       a[$1]=$1 in a ? sprintf("%s\n%*s %s",a[$1],length($1)," ",$2): $2
     }
  END{
       for(i in a)
           print i, a[i]
     }
    ' file
```

**Even if your input file is not sorted like below one, above one will work**

```
$ cat unsorted file
name1 123
name2 123
name1 324
name2 324
name2 456
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for `awk`, but most places there's `awk` there's also `perl`:

```
perl -lape 's/^(\w+)/" "x length($1)/e if $seen{$F[0]}++;'
```